# How to make UITextField blend into background after editing?

Tags: iphone, xcode, background, uitextfield

I ran into an issue that I've been researching for hours to no avail. I have a custom background in my app (using Xcode 4.2), and a few UITextFields. I was wondering if there is a way to make them blend into the background at launch, become active when tapped, and then blend back into the background while displaying the text after the editing is done?

Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by blending? what have you tried?

Comment: I set the background image of the UITextField to the current background in IB, but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: you mean that until you tap the textfield it should be invisible as a textfield and once tapped,it shows the keypad. right?

Comment: Yes, or possibly just displaying only the placeholder text until the user taps on it to edit it, then once the user is done editing it, only displaying the new text without the white background that UITextField usually has.

Comment: why don't you change the border style of the uitextfield?

Comment: Thank you so much Sarah! That works perfectly. I can't believe I didn't notice that, pretty embarrassing. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why don't you change the border style of the `uitextfield`?

Answer (score 2):

For this purpose you should Do Following things As

1)Clear the TextField Background

```
[myTextField  setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

2)Use UItextField Delegate method as Below

you can use that things as below

// make Clear BackGround  when you have started Editing in textField.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

//set here desired colour 

//or do here whatever you want

[myTextField  setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greyColour]];

}
```

// make Clear BackGround  when you hit Done key Of KeyBoard

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField {

    [myTextField  setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    [myTextField resignFirstResponder];

    return YES;
}
```

// make Clear BackGround When you End Typing

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

  [myTextField  setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set alpha value for the textfields as 1 for active mode and 0.25 for blend mode.

```
 [self.textField setAlpha:]
```